# Constraints and explicit template instantiation

Tags: c++, c++20

The following code does not compile in all of gcc 10.1, msvc 19.24, and clang 10.0.0:

```
template <int N>
struct A {
    void g() requires (N == 3) {}
    void f() requires (N == 3) { g(); }
};

template struct A<2>;
```

The error is something like

```
error C7500: 'g': no function satisfied its constraints
```

I'm somewhat surprised by this. Does this work as intended, is it a defect in a compiler, or is it a defect in the standard?

I was hoping such requires-statement to provide me with member functions which are present conditionally to the values of template arguments. A workaround is the following:

```
template <int N>
struct A {
    void g() requires (N == 3) {}
    template <bool = true>
    void f() requires (N == 3) { g(); }
};

template struct A<2>;
```

which compiles as expected, but introduces an extraneous template argument, whose sole purpose is to prevent instantiation.

Comment: I think it's a compiler bug, instantiating an object of type `A<2>` triggers no error on gcc, clang and msvc

Comment: That's what I'd like to think, but you never know with C++...

Comment: I reported bugs for all three compilers. Let's see what they think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the compilers; I reported it for all three compilers. [Visual Studio](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1110098/constraints-and-explicit-template-instantiation.html) has fixed this very recently in 16.7 Preview 1. [Gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96164) developers agreed that it is a bug. No word on Clang yet.

Comment: For Clang, this was broken in 13.0.0, but now seems to be fixed in 14.0.0.

Comment: Good to hear that!